# How to represent lists of blocks in Configgy?

Tags: scala, configuration-files

Configgy supports lists of strings as values and blocks of key/value pairs.
But it seems it does not support lists of blocks of key/value pairs as values.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using nested blocks:

```
contacts {
  c1 {
    name = "Joe Smith"
    email = "jsmith@example.com"
  }   

  c2 {
    name = "John Brown"
    email = "jbrown@example.com"
  }
}
```